# Is it possible to use an object variable as an array for a data source query 'in' clause

Tags: ssis

I'd like to have an OLEDB data source query similar to:

```
select * from MyTable where id in ( ? )
```

where the ? parameter is a variable holding an array of values.
Is this possible (or something like it)?

I understand that I could stick my data flow in a for-loop container, controlled by the variable, but I'd prefer that my data flow only execute once with all values.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done in one of solution.

```
- Execute SQL Task to read IN parameters from DB and store this to a temp 
  variable.


- Create a another variable and bind fetched value to sql query using an 
  expression and pass as "SQL Command from variable "to OLEDB source
```

[image: Build query using Expression]

[image]